# Docker - Timeout value connect was Timeout

Tags: python, docker, python-requests, docker-compose

I have just started out with Docker, and I am currently trying to run `docker-compose run --rm setup` on a docker-compose.yml file, but whenever I do, I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
    command()
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 118, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 750, in run
    run_one_off_container(container_options, self.project, service, options)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1136, in run_one_off_container
    rescale=False
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 388, in up
    warn_for_swarm_mode(self.client)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 614, in warn_for_swarm_mode
    info = client.info()
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 90, in info
    return self._result(self._get(self._url("/info")), True)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 189, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 515, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 582, in urlopen
    timeout_obj = self._get_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 309, in _get_timeout
    return Timeout.from_float(timeout)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 154, in from_float
    return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 97, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, 'connect')
  File "/home/wickywills/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 127, in _validate_timeout
    "int or float." % (name, value))
ValueError: Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=60, read=60, total=None), but it must be an int or float.
```

### Pip Freeze

```
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
boto==2.40.0
cached-property==1.3.0
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
cryptography==1.5
docker==2.4.2
docker-compose==1.14.0
docker-pycreds==0.2.1
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
duplicity==0.7.6
enum34==1.1.6
functools32==3.2.3.post2
idna==2.5
ipaddress==1.0.18
jsonschema==2.6.0
lockfile==0.12.2
mysql-connector-python==2.1.3
mysql-utilities==1.6.3
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
paramiko==2.0.0
pexpect==4.2.0
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygobject==3.22.0
pyodbc==3.0.10
pyOpenSSL==16.1.0
pysqlite==2.7.0
python-cloudfiles==1.7.10
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.1
six==1.10.0
texttable==0.8.8
urllib3==1.21.1
websocket-client==0.44.0
```

Seems like this is a common issue, without a real solution. I am running Ubuntu 16.10, and followed the installation instructions as per the Docker documentation. Can anyone advise?

Comment: What version of `requests` and `urllib3` do you have (use `pip freeze` to check)

Comment: @Alasdair `1.21.1`. Just added full `pip freeze` output to question.

Comment: Try uninstalling requests and installing again?

Comment: @Alasdair Uninstalling and reinstalling requests worked!

Comment: Great, glad it worked

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your error looks similar to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4927). The user closed the issue saying it was fixed by a new release of requests, so I would try upgrading `requests` in your virtual environment:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

From the comments, it sounds like you actually need to uninstall and then reinstall, rather than just upgrading.

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone have the same problem as me (same error message) the previous commands were not enough to correct the problem.

There was an old useless urllib3 install inside requests...
So I did:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Also try to upgrade selenium, for me that was the issue